# Magento 2.3.2 - Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I'm upgrading my Magento version from **2.2.4** to **2.3.2** and While trying to post any request in frontend getting "Invalid Form Key" error. Can't add product to cart, create account, Contact form submit. Nothing is submitting. Any idea how to resolve this?

*N.B: Already tried increasing max_input_vars not working.*

Comment: Try to clear cache  and reset your cookies

Comment: Try to clear the cache from var/cache directory.
Then clear browser cache. Especially clear or delete cookies.

Comment: It worked. Thanks to both of you